# Как узнать адрес домена на си?

Tags: c, сеть, dns

Допустим я хочу из программы узнать адрес домена google.com [здесь](https://www.rsdn.org/article/unix/sockets.xml) говорится что нужно сделать просто так:

```
struct hostent *host=gethostbyname("google.com");
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = host->h_addr;
printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr));
```

Но при каждом запуске выводятся разные ip(точно не гугла). Например:

```
IP: 48.160.173.213
```

Пробую заменить `google.com` на `localhost`, но выводится не 127.0.0.1:

```
IP: 80.62.213.191
```

Также пробую указать ip гугла   `172.217.16.196`, но выводится опять какая-то фигня

У меня выводятся всегда рандомные ip, а не те, которые принадлежат домену. В чем может быть проблема?

P.s несмотря на хорошие комментарии от andreymal, вопрос все еще нуждается в ответе

Comment: Как минимум в том, что `s_addr` это `unsigned long` и вы в него записываете адрес указателя, вот программа и печатает адрес указателя в виде IP-адреса

Comment: Кроме того, нужно помнить, что `h_addr` это указатель на структуру `in_addr` и обращаться с ним нужно соответствующим образом

Comment: @andreymal, так `h_addr` это макрос. `host->h_addr` тоже самое что и `host->h_addr_list[0]`

Comment: Ну так `h_addr_list[0]` это как раз указатель на структуру `in_addr`

Comment: @andreymal, Благодарю, буду разбираться

Comment: (однако на самом деле технически `h_addr_list` почему-то имеет тип `char**`, [объяснение этой странности на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658920))

Comment: @andreymal, ага, это меня очень запутало

Comment: @andreymal, этот char все портит, из-за него уже разыменованная структура `in_addr` не приводится к типу структуры, и использовать ее как структуру нельзя, компилятор думает что разыменованный адрес структуры имеет тип `char`, а не `struct in_addr`. Это ломает мой мозг, надеюсь в c++ такого нет

Answer (score 3):

Я дурак, надо было погуглить на английском языке, вот рабочий код, который извлекает ip домена - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-display-hostname-ip-address/

```
 // C program to display hostname 
// and IP address 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
 #include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    char hostbuffer[256]; 
    char *IPbuffer; 
    struct hostent *host_entry; 
    int hostname; 

    // To retrieve hostname 
    hostname = gethostname(hostbuffer, sizeof(hostbuffer)); 

    // To retrieve host information 
    host_entry = gethostbyname(hostbuffer); 

    // To convert an Internet network 
    // address into ASCII string 
    IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)host_entry->h_addr_list[0])); 

    printf("Hostname: %s\n", hostbuffer); 
    printf("Host IP: %s", IPbuffer); 

    return 0; 
}
```